# How to elegant use CoreData with Swift3 + Optional + NSOrderedSet + Generic

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

When using Core Data with Swift&Xcode8, i generate a model below, but i feel it's really hard to use :

1. The `chapter` relation to another model, and it's type was generated to `NSOrderedSet`
2. I actually can't use generic with `NSOrderedSet` such as `NSOrderedSet<Chapter>?`
3. I have to modify the collection with the generated accessors, it's annoying
4. all the attribute generated by Core Data is optional, with the model nested deep, i have to use a lot of guard or ? to unpack optional value

And i doubt that how you guys play with Core Data together with Swift ...

## :(

**Should i try using Realm instead ?**

`CourseDetail.swift` :

```
extension CourseDetail {
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var chapter: NSOrderedSet?
    @NSManaged public var author: NSOrderedSet?
}

// MARK: Generated accessors for chapter
extension CourseDetail {

    @objc(addChapterObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToChapter(_ value: Chapter)

    @objc(removeChapterObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromChapter(_ value: Chapter)

    @objc(addChapter:)
    @NSManaged public func addToChapter(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeChapter:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromChapter(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I don't use the generated class, I write them myself without using optionals except where needed. You don't have to use the generated classes.

Even the generated accessors can be hand written, they follow a simple Key-Value Coding naming convention.

If I were writing the class it would look something like:

```
@objc(CourseDetail)
public final class CourseDetail: NSManagedObject { // The actual class, no longer an extension.
    @NSManaged public var title: String
    @NSManaged public var chapter: NSSet
    @NSManaged public var author: NSSet

    // A convenience for fetch requests
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CourseDetail> {
        return NSFetchRequest<CourseDetail>(entityName: "CourseDetail");
    }

    @objc(addChapterObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToChapter(_ value: Chapter)

    @objc(removeChapterObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromChapter(_ value: Chapter)

    @objc(addChapter:)
    @NSManaged public func addToChapter(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeChapter:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromChapter(_ values: NSSet)

}
```